# Image of non-linear function $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

I have the function $F:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined $F(x,y)=(x^2-y-1,y)$ and wish to find its image (range, whatever): the subset $F(\mathbb{R}^2)=\{F(x,y)|(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2.$

Well, $\{F(x,y)|(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\}=\{(x^2-y-1,y)|(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\},$ so I am looking for ordered pairs $(u,v)$ satisfying $(u,v)=(x^2-y-1,y)$. I got that $(x,y)=(\pm \sqrt{u + v + 1},v),$ but am not sure where to go from here, or if these first steps are even correct.

I have also noticed that $F(-x,y)=F(x,y)$, but I'm not sure what to do with this.

What is the general procedure for these problems? When things are linear I know exactly what to do.

Comment: Another approach is to first think about the linear function $(a,b)\mapsto(a-b,b)$, and how (the parts of) its image relate to the image of $F$.

Comment: I removed the `differential-geometry` tag since it is irrelevant here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. We know that $(u,v)\in F(\mathbb R^2)$ if and only if $u=x^2-v-1$ for some $x\in\mathbb R$. This is only true if we can find an $x\in \mathbb R$ such that $x^2=u+v+1$. This is only possible when $u+v+1\geq 0$. Thus
$$F(\mathbb R^2)=\{(u,v)\in\mathbb R^2:v\geq-u-1\}.$$

Comment: Got it. I wasn't sure how exactly to incorporate the domain of the square root, but this clears everything up, thank you.